# Migrating a Flutter android (API 29) app's downloaded media(images, videos, PDF) to confirm to Scoped Storage of Android 11 (API Level 30)

Tags: android, flutter, android-11, scoped-storage

We have a flutter app similar to Whatsapp (say **MessagingApp**) for broadcasting messages with media (images, videos, PDF) within a closed group of people.

The current flutter app's android **targetSdkVersion is 29** and uses the **Legacy Storage** using file path access method to read and write media files as described below.

All the app's media files are downloaded under the base directory `/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp`.

Following are the example file path's of various media:

Sample Downloaded Image's path `/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Images/20210410_111512.jpg`

Sample Downloaded Video's path `/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Videos/20210410_111513.mp4`

Sample Downloaded PDF's path `/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Documents/20210410_11151.pdf`

To download an image the [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package is used:

`dio.download(imageHttpUrl, '/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Images/20210410_111512.jpg',)`

The downloaded image is rendered in the app using the `Image.file` widget:
`Image.file(File('/storage/emulated/0/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Images/20210410_111512.jpg'))`

**The downloaded images can be viewed from android's Gallery app.**

Starting November 2021, Playstore forces the targetSdkVersion to be 30 and in the API Level 30's Scoped Storage model, apps cannot create folders directly in the "Shared Storage".

In Scoped Storage the files can be downloaded and used from the app specific directory - `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.test.MessagingApp/files`
But they will not accessible to other(Gallery) apps.

Other than that Scoped Storage mentions to use "MediaStoreAPI" for managing media.

How to manage and handle downloaded media in Flutter android (API 30) with the new Scoped Storage of Android 11?

Also i noticed on emulator running android 11 and app with targetSdkVersion 30, the app cannot create a folder in the root storage `/storage/emulated/0/`, but the android folders "Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures and so on" are freely accesible, that is new folders can be created under them using the existing code i.e. the image path can be changed to `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MessagingApp/MessagingApp_Images/20210410_111512.jpg` and it works.

What is the best practice for using the new Scoped Storage of Android 11 for a Flutter android app?

Comment: This link suggests to migrate the top level app specific folder into Music or Download folder and your existing code works without any change: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jn5azi/android_11_dodges_a_bullet_apps_creating_a_folder/

Comment: It would be interesting to know how other messenger apps like Whatsapp, Telegram etc. are going to adapt to the Scoped Storage model. As of version 2.21.9.13 Whatsapp still uses legacy storage (Using the default Whatsapp folder at the root of Internal Storage) on Android 11. The Viber app has given their adaption stratergy at the below link https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/bringing-modern-storage-to-vibers-users.html